# Problem with jQuery's nth-child(n+2) with table structure

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

The jQuery's nth-child selector isn't working as I expect it to work with the below HTML. It returns 0 instead of (total number SELECTs - 1). It works just fine if I get rid of the TABLE and keep only SELECTs. I noticed that it works fine if I use `nth-child(n+1)` whether I keep the TABLE structure or not. Moving the alert code to a button click event didn't change anything.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>             
            <select>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("select:nth-child(n+2)").length);
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvkUP/).

jQuery 1.6.2; IE8 (can't help it!); I'm  not using table to create page layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is every select element but the first one then just use `select:gt(0)`

The reason `:nth-child(n+2)` doesn't work is because the select elements do not have the same parent.  :nth-child depends on counting children of the same parent.

Take a look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/MvkUP/1/

Comment: Thanks David, that is exactly what I have used to get around this problem. I asked this question to know why nth-child(n+2) doesn't work.

Comment: @Lobo I updated my answer to show why `:nth-child` doesn't work

Comment: Thanks sir. The answer was always right there in the question - **child**! I updated the fiddle, I think, [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/MvkUP/2/) explains it better.